# Casting a radio button with parseInt returns a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a set of radio buttons which are set using the below methods. At the point of handleChange I'm casting the value to a integer if the target element is a radio button.

On the initial handleChange the typeof is returning a number however subsequent calls are returning the state as a string.

My understanding of TypeScript is the language is strongly typed so shouldn't be cast in this way?

```
<input id="EvalLikelihood_1" name="EvalLikelihood" type="radio" value="1" checked={this.state.EvalLikelihood == 1} onChange={this.handleChange}/>

private handleChange(event): void { 
      const target = event.target;
      console.log(parseInt(target.value));
        const value = target.type === 'radio' ? target.value : parseInt(target.value);
        const name = target.name;
        this.setState({
          [name]: value
        });
        console.log(typeof this.state.EvalLikelihood)
        console.log(this.state.EvalLikelihood)
      }
this.state = {
      EvalLikelihood: 0,
      safety: 0,
      security: 0,
      enviroment: 0,
      finance: 0,
      operational: 0,
      legal: 0,
      reputation: 0,
      inherentRisk: 0
    };

EvalLikelihood: number;
```

Thanks for looking at this issue.

Comment: Your script has errors, unexpected token `.`.

Comment: You're parsing to an int if the target element type is _not_ a radio button.

Comment: replace your ternary operator line to `const value = parseInt(target.value, 10)`  [`worked fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/174225/)

Comment: Thanks @TheReason this has solved my issue. :)

Can you explain what the problem was with the previous line? Just started working with react/typescript a week ago, so if I can learn from this it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your *ternary operator line*.

```
const value = target.type === 'radio' ? target.value : parseInt(target.value);
```

Here you look at `target.type` and if it's definitely `radio` it returns the current value which is a *string*. You don't need `ternary operator` in this case because your `input` has type `radio` so you need just convert it the string value to `number`.

The solution is simple: replace the line from above to:

```
const value = parseInt(target.value, 10)
```

[`Worked example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/174228/).

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is only a superset of JavaScript, not a different language. When compiled regular javascript is produced. I don't know why it works the first time for you though. Try changing your code to:

```
const value = typeof target.type === 'number' ? target.value : parseInt(target.value);
```

Comment: Perhaps poor wording on my part semantically describing TypeScript.

The target.type is from the event however which is the input type of radio.